# Constructor for Classes with Array Field in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor, field

I have a class called "File" with private field "bool[] bits". How should I create a constructor for this "File" class which only includes "bool[] bits"? Size of array is unknown.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Size of built-in arrays in C++ is part of its type. So, you can not create an array without specifying its size. *BTW, Your code `bool[] bits` is not a valid syntax in C++.*

```
class File
{
    std::vector<bool> bits;
public:
    File(int size) : bits(size) {}
};
```